# Moving data between two DB2 9.7 databases

Tags: db2, etl

Does DB2 9.7 offer tools to move data between two databases? And only from selected tables? The schema varies slightly between the two, mostly so that the destination database contains some new columns (will be left as null of course) and some columns have changed datatype.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use federation between the two databases. You create "aliases" from one database in the other one, and then you just perform select or other operations on the remote table. For example, you can use a "load from cursor" using an alias.

Another way to do that, is using db2move or specifically export/import, but you need to deal with files.

Remember, federation is free between db2 databases, no extra license is required.